# PySpark: Moving rows from one dataframe into another if column values are not found in second dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark, rows

I have two spark dataframes with similar schemas:
DF1:

```
id       category  flag
123abc   type 1     1 
456def   type 1     1
789ghi   type 2     0
101jkl   type 3     0
```

Df2:

```
id       category  flag
123abc   type 1     1 
456def   type 1     1
789ghi   type 2     1
101xyz   type 3     0
```

DF1 has more data than DF2 so I cannot replace it. However, DF2 will have ids not found in DF1, as well as several IDs with more accurate flag data. This means there there are two situations that I need resolved:

1. `789ghi` has a different flag and needs to overwrite the 789ghi in
   DF1.
2. `101xyz` is not found in DF1 and needs to be moved over

Each dataframe is millions of rows, so I am looking for an efficient way to perform this operation. I am not sure if this is a situation that requires an outer join or anti-join.

Comment: You could do df1 anti join df2 and then union that result to df2. That way you have everything from df2 and only the things from df1 which are not in df2.

Comment: This worked the best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can union the two dataframes and keep the first record for each id.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, col

df = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName,[df2,df1])

df = df.withColumn('row_num',monotonically_increasing_id())

window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy('row_num')

df = (df.withColumn('rank', rank().over(window))
        .filter(col('rank') == 1)).drop('rank','row_num')
```

Output

```
+------+--------+----+
|    id|category|flag|
+------+--------+----+
|101jkl|  type 3|   0|
|101xyz|  type 3|   0|
|123abc|  type 1|   1|
|456def|  type 1|   1|
|789ghi|  type 2|   1|
+------+--------+----+
```

Comment: but how am I sure the first record will always be from DF2 in these cases?

Comment: because it's first in the union list `[df2,df1]`  This will put df1 records after df2

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
I would find ids in df1 not in df2 and put them into a subset df
I would then union the subset with df2.

Or

Option 2:
Find elements in df1 that are in df2 and drop those rows and then union df2.
The approach I take would obviously be based on which is less expensive computationally.

Option 1 code

```
s=df1.select('id').subtract(df2.select('id')).collect()[0][0]

df2.union(df1.filter(col('id')==s)).show()
```

Outcome

```
+------+--------+----+
|    id|category|flag|
+------+--------+----+
|123abc|  type 1|   1|
|456def|  type 1|   1|
|789ghi|  type 2|   1|
|101xyz|  type 3|   0|
|101jkl|  type 3|   0|
+------+--------+----+
```

Comment: Please let me know if this helps or if you need any clarification. Happy to answer questions and assist further. happy coding